# Can't call private class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting the following error when trying to call a private method inside the same class:

`undefined local variable or method` a_private_method' for AClass (NameError)`

Here the class:

```
class AClass
  def self.public_method
    file = a_private_method
  end

  private

  def a_private_method
    do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is `a_private_method` an instance method when you seemingly don't need an instance to use it?

Comment: @3limin4t0rmay I ask you to elaborate more on your comment?

Comment: More often than not when working with a class method you don't have access to an instance (unless your class method is a factory or is passed an instance). Without instance there is no way to access instance methods. If `a_private_method` is some sort of helper function (only using its arguments eg. does not explicitly or implicitly use `self`) there is no reason to define it as an instance method. Instead define it as a class method so both the class and class instance have access to it. Or define it in a module so it can be imported (`include`/`extend`) by those who need the helper.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to call an instance method from a class method, this does of course not work.

Try this

```rb
class AClass
  class << self
    def public_method
      file = a_private_method
    end

    private

    def a_private_method
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use `self` as the receiver similar to what you already did but pleases be aware that moving the method to the `private` part of your class does not work in this case. You could use `private_class_method` though.

```rb
class AClass
    def self.public_method
      file = a_private_method
    end

    def self.a_private_method
      # do something
    end
    private_class_method :a_private_method
  end
end
```

See https://jakeyesbeck.com/2016/01/24/ruby-private-class-methods and https://dev.to/adamlombard/ruby-class-methods-vs-instance-methods-4aje.